# Sources for linux distros other than distrowatch

Tags: linux-distributions

I'm collecting all linux distributions that are available on the internet as long as its free. And I found that distrowatch has lots, but then when I tried to download from their site. Its so slow 5kbps. When I download psp games it is 101 kbps. So the problem is not really my connection. Its on distro watch. What other sites could you recommend for downloading linux distros that allows fast downloads.
By the way let me share to you an  awesome os I found out:

- http://www.kahelos.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[University Of Kent Mirror Service](http://www.mirrorservice.org/platforms/linux) hosts many distro mirrors - most of the distro main sites use them as an official mirror.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve them on the official distro site. It use to be linked by distrowatch distro-specific page.